# Is there a way to receive data notifications in flutter when the app is killed?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement custom ui for push notifications in android (title, body, image loaded from url),

the firebase_messaging dart plugin has a limitation for receiving data notifications when the app is killed.

using data payload instead of notifications payload is the option to draw custom ui notifications in android natively.

Is there a way to receive data notifications in flutter when the app is killed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a background message handler in headless function and use firebase local notification plugin to show the notification

this tutorial will definitely help you 
https://medium.com/@sylvainduch/firebase-messaging-catch-them-all-3f9c594734d7

Comment: I have implemented your solution which worked in android but not in iOS. When iOS app is killed or terminated, onBackgroundMessage, onResume not called. Do you know any solution?

Comment: i don't think this is possible in iOS

Comment: It is possible in iOS. You need to register for remote notification and background receive under app capabilities in the iOS build settings.